# Google Translate bookmarklet

Tags: chrome, google-apps

I'm looking for a Google Translate bookmarklet that actually works. I've searched around for it and the ones on the web doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Basically looking for a quick way to get Google Translate to translate a page when I want to but without having the classic Chrome prompt pop up whenever viewing a page in another language OR having it translate automatically every time - just when I want it to.

I don't want a toolbar/extension/app either.